# how to import relationships from hasura graphql engine through graphql schema?

Tags: graphql, hasura

Hasura allows exporting schema through this method as described on this page:
https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/guides/export-graphql-schema.html

I would like to know how to import existing schema into it that includes relationships between types, where the relationships were added using UI.

Comment: looking for same thing, still no luck.